# What is the role of 'quem' in this quote from Cicero?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In Cicero's "ad Familiares" 12.10.2 there is:

> "quem quidem ego exercitum quibuscumque potuero rebus ornabo;" =

> "This army, indeed, I will compliment by all the means in my power." (Perseus)

Why isn't the accusative, (from "ornabo"), "this army", given as, (masculine) "hunc exercitum"; why use a relative pronoun, (masculine, accusative) "quem"? This, usually, introducing a relative clause would be deployed for something like, "The army (nominative) which ("quem") I will compliment". In this example, such translating does not apply and "the army" ("exercitus") is in the accusative, "exercitum", anyway.

How does "quem" work, here?

A secondary point: Shouldn't future-perfect, "potuero", be completed before the future, "ornabo", can be invoked? Here, they will occur together, inevitably?

Comment: On potuero and ornabo, I imagine an elided verb such as parare or collocare. Gathering the resources logically proceeds the outfitting. "I will outfit this army with whatever resources I will have been able (to amass)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very common. Relative pronouns are often used to introduce the next clause when the meaning is something like "et [is,ea,id]."

See [Allen and Greenough](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Apart%3D2%3Asection%3D4%3Asubsection%3D5%3Asmythp%3D303):

> When the antecedent is in a different sentence, the relative is often equivalent to a demonstrative with a conjunction: quae cum ita sint (=et cum ea ita sint), [and] since this is so.